# I am utilizing the https://github.com/Yacubane/esp32-arduino-matter library to create a Matter node, how do I create a new pairing code?

Tags: arduino, pairing

I have been successful in utilizing https://github.com/Yacubane/esp32-arduino-matter in the Arduino IDE to create a 2 relay momentary 'button' pusher for connected RF remote.  Works great.  I would like to create additional versions but have found the code generates the same pairing code each time, not allowing me to enroll multiple iterations of the same code on different devices (i.e. one esp32 module + relays to control the front window roller shade remote, and one with the same code, but different pairing code, for a different esp32 module + relays for the back window roller shade remote).

Where or how do I change the pairing code in Matter?

I have dug through the code as best possible to try to find matching strings of the pairing code that is presented in the serial monitor window.  The code presented works fine, but not obvious how to generate a different one.